Launching kivy app onto android phone using usb
I'm making an app using kivy (python) through VSCode. I want to launch the app on my android phone by connecting a usb cord. I turned on usb debugging but I'm not sure where to go from here. How can I see the app on my phone?
I turned on usb debugging but I'm sure where to go from here. How can I see the app on my phone?

there are a lot of open questions here.

What OS are you using?
Did you already create an .apk file with buildozer?
Did you already install the android debug bridge (adb)

If the answers are linux, yes and yes, you should be able to do:
adb install path/to/file.apk
Windows is a lot more complicated but this video helps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzsvN3fuBA0&t=637s
